# $\forall\, 0\to N\to M\to F\to 0 $ exact, $\forall R$-module $E$, $F$ is flat $\implies 0 \to N\otimes E\to M\otimes E\to F\otimes E \to0$ is exact.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, flatness

In $R$-mod category, $\forall\, 0\to N\to M\to F\to 0 $ is short exact sequence, $\forall R$-module $E$.

$\forall\, 0\to N\to M\to F\to 0 $ exact, $\forall R$-module $E$, $F$ is flat $\implies 0 \to N\otimes E\to M\otimes E\to F\otimes E \to0$ is exact.

How to prove $F$ is flat $\implies$$\quad0 \to N\otimes E\to M\otimes E\to F\otimes E \to0$ is exact?

My thought:

I gave an answer. I wonder if there's an alternative and more direct proof, **just** using definition of flat module instead of introducing another short exact sequence, since it's not easy for beginners to think of that method. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: $K=E{}{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, I put it right.

Comment: I don't think you mean to say that $(\cdot \otimes E)$ is an exact functor in the original title because it seems it only preserves exactness of a specific kind of short exact sequence.

Comment: @AniruddhAgarwal Yes, you're right. I intended to shorten the title but made a mistake. Thanks for mention that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try and make the question more precise. You are given a short exact sequence $0\to M\to N\to F\to 0$, with $F$ flat and you want to prove that, for every $E$, the sequence $0\to M\otimes E\to N\otimes E\to F\otimes E\to 0$ is exact.

Take an exact sequence $0\to X\to Y\to E\to 0$ with $Y$ projective and build the diagram with exact rows and columns
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
{} @. {} @. {} @. 0 \\
 @. @. @. @VVV \\
{} @. M\otimes X @>a>> N\otimes X @>b>> F\otimes X @>>> 0 \\
@. @VcVV @VdVV @VeVV @. \\
0 @>>> M\otimes Y @>f>> N\otimes Y @>g>> F\otimes Y @>>> 0 \\
@. @VhVV @ViVV @VjVV @. \\
{} @. M\otimes E @>k>> N\otimes E @>l>> F\otimes E @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV @. \\
{} @. 0 @. 0 @. 0
\end{CD}
$$
where we have used the fact that $F$ and $Y$ are flat.

Here's the diagram chasing. Let $x\in\ker k$; then $x=h(y)$ and $if(y)=kh(y)=0$, so $f(y)\in\ker i$; hence $f(y)=d(z)$. Since $eb(z)=gd(z)=gf(z)=0$, we conclude $b(z)\in\ker e$, so $b(z)=0$. This implies $z=a(t)$.

Thus $fc(t)=da(t)=d(z)=f(y)$; since $f$ is injective, we have $y=c(t)$ and finally
$$
x=h(y)=hc(t)=0
$$

Comment: Thanks for graph chasing. Actually, I want a direct proof without introducing another short exact sequence.

Comment: Let me just remark the same proof may be found in Serge Lang XVI Sec.3 (Flat Modules) , Lemma 3.3 (p. 614)

Comment: @Divide1918 I didn't look there: it's a pretty standard method.

Answer (score 1):

We can choose a short exact sequence $0\to K\to L\to E\to 0 $ s.t. $L$ is free module, and use properties: $(1)\,\otimes $ is right exact $(2)L$ is free ($\implies$flat) $(3) F$ is flat for diagram

$$N\otimes K\to M\otimes K\to F\otimes K$$
$$\downarrow \quad\quad\quad\quad\downarrow \quad\quad\quad\quad\downarrow$$
$$N\otimes L\to M\otimes L\to F\otimes L$$
$$\downarrow \quad\quad\quad\quad\downarrow \quad\quad\quad\quad\downarrow$$
$$N\otimes E\to M\otimes E\to F\otimes E$$
Snake Lemma then yields $\quad0 \to N\otimes E\to M\otimes E\to F\otimes E \to0$.

Using the same idea, we can show this:

$0 \to F' \to F \to F''$ is exact and $F''$ is flat, then $F'$ is flat $\iff F$ is flat.

Especially, for exact sequence $0 \to F^0\to F^1 \to \cdots \to F^n$, if $F^1, \cdots, F^n$ are flat, then $F^0$ is flat.

Comment: I'm confused about how you're applying the snake lemma here.

Comment: @AniruddhAgarwal See the other answer and try to find the snake :)